# CORS restriction from AWS when calling a webAPI from a reactJS application

Tags: reactjs, vb.net, amazon-web-services, cors

I have a visual basic application that I wrote installed on an AWS elastic beanstalk environment.  I also have a reactJS application installed on an AWS S3 instance.  Within the reactJS application, I execute the following fetch:

```
var url = "";  
var which = "login";
var passedData = "6007sP0001????DEMI0000000000%20%20%20%20INTERNET/093000050vista19%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20money19%20%20%20";   
switch (which) {
    case "login":        
            url = "https://webaccuapi-dv.accurecord-direct.com/api/login?mqRequest=" + passedData;
            break;
    case "homepage":
            url = "https://webaccuapi-dv.accurecord-direct.com/api/homepage?mqRequest=" + passedData;
            break;
}

const options = { method: 'GET' };

var returnString = "";

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("do fetch at ", new Date().toLocaleString())
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        if (myJson == undefined) 
        {
            returnString = "fetch failed";
        } 
        else 
        { 
            returnString = myJson[0];
            console.log("return from fetch at ", new Date().toLocaleString())
        }
        resolve(returnString);
    }); 
});
```

The code in the visual basic application contains the following code which I found in another stackoverflow article months ago (but I dont remember where):

```vb
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.Cors

Public Module WebApiConfig
Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    ' Web API configuration and services
    Dim Cors = New EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:8080,http://401kmobileapp.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com,https://my401kapp.accurecord-direct.com", "*", "*")

    config.EnableCors(Cors)
    ' Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
End Module
```

My understanding, as limited as it is, is that the code in the visual basic application should allow requests from http://localhost:8080, http://401kmobileapp.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com, and https://my401kapp.accurecord-direct.com to process and any request from any other url will be rejected by CORS.

Unfortunately, for some reason, CORS is rejecting my reactJS's requests.  When I launch the reactJS app (located at https://my401kapp.accurecord-direct.com/) and I enter a user ID and password (the user ID is 'vista19' and the password is 'money19' - I dont mind sharing these since they are test user ID and passwords) I get the following error in the browser console:

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://webaccuapi-dv.accurecord-direct.com/api/login?mqRequest=6007sP0001????DEMI0000000000%20%20%20%20INTERNET/093000050vista19%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20money19%20%20%20'
>   from origin 'https://my401kapp.accurecord-direct.com' has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set
>   the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS
>   disabled.

I can get the entire process to work from localhost on my development machine if I replace all https with http and as long as I have http://localhost:8080 in the list of urls in my visual basic application.  If I remove http://localhost:8080 and run locally, I get a CORS error.  If I put http://localhost:8080 back into the list, I get my data back.

So, I know the process works correctly under http but I can not get it to work under https.

Comment: What HTTP status code are you getting for the response? (Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.) When I try https://webaccuapi-dv.accurecord-direct.com/api/login?mqRequest=6007sP0001????DEMI0000000000%20%20%20%20INTERNET/093000050vista19%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20money19%20%20%20 I get a **408 Request Timeout** error. (And the response has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin because no 408 error is ever going to have additional headers, since it indicates a timeout before the request could actually get handled…)

Comment: I see this in the console:  GET https://webaccuapi-dv.accurecord-direct.com/api/login?mqRequest=6007sP0001????DEMI0000000000%20%20%20%20INTERNET/093000050vista19%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20money19%20%20%20 net::ERR_ABORTED 408 (REQUEST_TIMEOUT). So something is preventing my webAPI from processing? And then CORS fails because webAPI is timing out?  Strange since everything works properly under http.  It only fails when running under https.  So maybe something is wrong in the S3 environment hosting my webAPI?